# AngularJS one-time binding for controller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot one-time bind any var that is binded through the controller without using the $scope.

My controller:

```
angular.module('mydummyapp').controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
var self = this;
self.test= 'test';})
```

HTML:

```
<h4 class="modal-title">{{::MyCtrl.test}}</h4>
```

The `test` var is binded but when I update (on a `<input>`  with `ng-model`) it will be changed on the supposed `::MyCtrl.test`. If on the controller I do a `$scope.test='xxx'` and on the view I use `{{::test}}` it will actually work well. 
So how can I make this work with the my initial approach? I'm asking this because I guess it's the correct way nowadays not using the `$scope`.

Cheers

Comment: can you add a bit more of your HTML code just to check that the controller as syntax is correct?

Comment: As has been stated by multiple people here, the code you are presenting here should work correctly, but the code which could potentially cause this not to work has not been shown in your sample (i.e. the line where you are declaring `ng-controller`).

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work with you initial approach ...

In your template use the ControllerAs as [approach](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y032) as suggest in John Papas AngularJS Style guides.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as MyCtrl">
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{::MyCtrl.test}}</h4>
</div>
```

Ideally you should change `MyCtrl as MyCtrl` to `MyCtrl as vm` and in your controller ...

```
....
var vm = this;
vm.test = 'test';
....
```